# Pop-up info box in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code and would like some help  adding pop-up info boxes for each custom marker. Currently I can set the coordinates for each marker in my code but I would also like to add additional information in a pop-up info box once the marker is clicked. I cant seem to get a pop-up info box to work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cycle Trails Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-    scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map_canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1000px;
      background-color: #2D333C;
    }
    #legend {
      font-family: Helvetica;
      color: #FFD900;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      padding: 25px;
      margin: 25px;
      border: 1px solid #FFD900;
    }
    #legend h3 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    #legend img {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script>
    var map; // google map object
    var markers = []; // we well store the markers here 


    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.269954, 174.225516),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,



        <!-- Let's style the map with custom colours and opacity -->   

        styles: [{
          featureType: 'poi.business',
          elementType: ' labels.icon',
          stylers: [{
            visibility: 'on'
          }, {
            hue: '#ff00db'
          }, {
            lightness: 0
          }, {
            saturation: 0
          }]
        }]
      });



      <!-- create KML layer -->

      var myKmlOptions = {
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
      }

      var kmlLayer_1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://private.aatravel.co.nz/accommodation/1038668/proof14/final.kml", myKmlOptions);
      var kmlLayer_2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://private.aatravel.co.nz/accommodation/1038668/proof14/sep.kml", myKmlOptions);
      kmlLayer_1.setMap(map);
      kmlLayer_2.setMap(map);







      <!-- Asynchronous Loading -->
      function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
          '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }

      window.onload = loadScript;











      <!-- Let's create the legend -->


      var iconBase = 'https://i.imgur.com/';
      var icons = {
        travel: {
          name: 'AA Traveller office',
          icon: iconBase + '2BNbLmG.png'
        },
        isite: {
          name: 'I-Site',
          icon: iconBase + 'kx9a1sc.png'
        },

        accommodation: {
          name: 'Accommodation',
          icon: iconBase + 'BJ4o7ad.png'
        },

        camping: {
          name: 'Camping',
          icon: iconBase + 'EIcei8n.png'
        },


        food: {
          name: 'Food and Beverage',
          icon: iconBase + 'c5aaWcb.png'
        },


        toilets: {
          name: 'Toilets',
          icon: iconBase + 'ID2zzXg.png'
        },


        waters: {
          name: 'Drinking Water',
          icon: iconBase + '5u3yvH1.png'
        },


        todo: {
          name: 'Things to do',
          icon: iconBase + 'L3Z9xWv.png'
        },

        viewing: {
          name: 'Viewing points',
          icon: iconBase + 'DTf6oIp.png'
        }
      };
      <!-- Adding the markers now -->
      function addMarker(feature) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: feature.position,
          icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
          map: map
        });
        markers.push({
          marker: marker,
          type: feature.type
        });
      }

      <!-- Add the legend locations -->


      var features = [
        <!-- AA Travel -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.750002, 174.729471),
          type: 'travel'
        },




        <!-- I Site -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.226583, 175.335536),
          type: 'isite'
        },





        <!-- Accommodation -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.807404, 175.144404),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.808155, 175.474612),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.776782, 171.504106),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-43.820004, 172.965288),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-44.626974, 169.317827),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-46.522343, 168.455400),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },





        <!-- Camping -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.556301, 174.693964),
          type: 'camping'
        },






        <!-- Food and Beverage -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.368372, 176.847826),
          type: 'food'
        },





        <!-- Water -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.241622, 174.782397),
          type: 'waters'
        },







        <!-- Things to do -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.339016, 176.298510),
          type: 'todo'
        },






        <!-- Toilets -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-42.788153, 172.497240),
          type: 'toilets'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.878568, 173.837572),
          type: 'toilets'
        },





        <!-- Viewing spots -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-43.890775, 171.838061),
          type: 'viewing'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.676004, 178.429858),
          type: 'viewing'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.278658, 173.763491),
          type: 'viewing'
        }

      ];

      for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
        addMarker(feature);
      }

      var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
      var i = 0;
      for (var key in icons) {
        var type = icons[key];
        var name = type.name;
        var icon = type.icon;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleType(this, event, \'' + key + '\')"><img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
        legend.appendChild(div);
        i++;
      }
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
    }

    function toggleType(elm, event, type) {
      var on = elm.checked;
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].type == type) {
          markers[i].marker.setMap(on ? map : null);
        }
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div id="legend">
    <h3>Points of Interest</h3>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh by the way, I'm completely new to web programming.. so go easy on me!

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553470/how-do-i-add-a-title-box-to-a-custom-google-map/30553626#30553626

Comment: Thank you , but i'm looking for a info box similar to: http://www.nzcycletrail.com/twin-coast-cycle-trail/map If you click on the stars a info box appears. I need to know how I would integrate this into my code..

Comment: I don't see any code for any type of infowindow. What have you tried to implement the desired "pop-up" functionality?  Where do you expect the content to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Steps below with comments:

1. Construct an infoWindow object `new google.maps.InfoWindow()`
2. In the creation of each marker bind a click event to that marker. Pass at a minimum, the marker you created to that callback through a closure.
3. The callback will `setContent` of the infoWindow. You'll probably want to dynamically create an html string and send it to `setContent`
4. The callback will then open the info on the `map` over the clicked `marker`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cycle Trails Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-    scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map_canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1000px;
      background-color: #2D333C;
    }
    #legend {
      font-family: Helvetica;
      color: #FFD900;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      padding: 25px;
      margin: 25px;
      border: 1px solid #FFD900;
    }
    #legend h3 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    #legend img {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script>
    var map; // google map object
    var markers = []; // we well store the markers here 


    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.269954, 174.225516),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,



        <!-- Let's style the map with custom colours and opacity -->   

        styles: [{
          featureType: 'poi.business',
          elementType: ' labels.icon',
          stylers: [{
            visibility: 'on'
          }, {
            hue: '#ff00db'
          }, {
            lightness: 0
          }, {
            saturation: 0
          }]
        }]
      });



      <!-- create KML layer -->

      var myKmlOptions = {
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
      }

      var kmlLayer_1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://private.aatravel.co.nz/accommodation/1038668/proof14/final.kml", myKmlOptions);
      var kmlLayer_2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://private.aatravel.co.nz/accommodation/1038668/proof14/sep.kml", myKmlOptions);
      kmlLayer_1.setMap(map);
      kmlLayer_2.setMap(map);







      <!-- Asynchronous Loading -->
      function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
          '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }

      window.onload = loadScript;











      <!-- Let's create the legend -->


      var iconBase = 'https://i.imgur.com/';
      var icons = {
        travel: {
          name: 'AA Traveller office',
          icon: iconBase + '2BNbLmG.png'
        },
        isite: {
          name: 'I-Site',
          icon: iconBase + 'kx9a1sc.png'
        },

        accommodation: {
          name: 'Accommodation',
          icon: iconBase + 'BJ4o7ad.png'
        },

        camping: {
          name: 'Camping',
          icon: iconBase + 'EIcei8n.png'
        },


        food: {
          name: 'Food and Beverage',
          icon: iconBase + 'c5aaWcb.png'
        },


        toilets: {
          name: 'Toilets',
          icon: iconBase + 'ID2zzXg.png'
        },


        waters: {
          name: 'Drinking Water',
          icon: iconBase + '5u3yvH1.png'
        },


        todo: {
          name: 'Things to do',
          icon: iconBase + 'L3Z9xWv.png'
        },

        viewing: {
          name: 'Viewing points',
          icon: iconBase + 'DTf6oIp.png'
        }
      };
      // make one infoWindow
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      <!-- Adding the markers now -->
      function addMarker(feature) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: feature.position,
          icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
          map: map
        });
        // bind a to the marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            openInfoWindow(marker, feature) // pass in feature as closure
        });
        markers.push({
          marker: marker,
          type: feature.type
        });
      }

      // generic callback whenever an info window is clicked
      function openInfoWindow(marker, feature) {
         // i'm unsure of where you're data will come to populate the infoWindow, it could come from the `feature` object (the same thing that you used to create the marker)
         infoWindow.setContent('<h3>Type: ' + feature.type + '<h3>');
         infoWindow.open(map, marker); // open the infoWindow above the marker. the maps API will bind the close button click for you. 
      
      }

      <!-- Add the legend locations -->


      var features = [
        <!-- AA Travel -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.750002, 174.729471),
          type: 'travel'
        },




        <!-- I Site -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.226583, 175.335536),
          type: 'isite'
        },





        <!-- Accommodation -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.807404, 175.144404),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.808155, 175.474612),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.776782, 171.504106),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-43.820004, 172.965288),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-44.626974, 169.317827),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-46.522343, 168.455400),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },





        <!-- Camping -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.556301, 174.693964),
          type: 'camping'
        },






        <!-- Food and Beverage -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.368372, 176.847826),
          type: 'food'
        },





        <!-- Water -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.241622, 174.782397),
          type: 'waters'
        },







        <!-- Things to do -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.339016, 176.298510),
          type: 'todo'
        },






        <!-- Toilets -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-42.788153, 172.497240),
          type: 'toilets'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.878568, 173.837572),
          type: 'toilets'
        },





        <!-- Viewing spots -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-43.890775, 171.838061),
          type: 'viewing'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.676004, 178.429858),
          type: 'viewing'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.278658, 173.763491),
          type: 'viewing'
        }

      ];

      for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
        addMarker(feature);
      }

      var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
      var i = 0;
      for (var key in icons) {
        var type = icons[key];
        var name = type.name;
        var icon = type.icon;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleType(this, event, \'' + key + '\')"><img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
        legend.appendChild(div);
        i++;
      }
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
    }

    function toggleType(elm, event, type) {
      var on = elm.checked;
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].type == type) {
          markers[i].marker.setMap(on ? map : null);
        }
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div id="legend">
    <h3>Points of Interest</h3>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this helped a lot! Just one last question, how would I create info boxes custom to each marker? for example in my code I have multiple Accommodation markers, how would I create a info-box with different text  for each marker? Sorry I'm completely new to this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You'll need the content to come from _somewhere_ In `openInfoWindow`, the second argument is the individual feature, whatever data you used to create the marker could also be used to build the html string to set the content in the info window.

The only thing you have on each of your feature objects a lat/lng and `type`.  It'd be pretty easy to add more data here. 

I updated my answer to give you an example of displaying data dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Just declared variable `infoWindow` above `addMarker` and in its `actionListener` opened and set the content for infowindow

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
           infoWindow.setContent('Hi');
           infoWindow.open(map,this);
        });
```

check out:

```js
    var map; // google map object
    var markers = []; // we well store the markers here 


    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.269954, 174.225516),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,



        <!-- Let's style the map with custom colours and opacity -->   

        styles: [{
          featureType: 'poi.business',
          elementType: ' labels.icon',
          stylers: [{
            visibility: 'on'
          }, {
            hue: '#ff00db'
          }, {
            lightness: 0
          }, {
            saturation: 0
          }]
        }]
      });



      <!-- create KML layer -->

      var myKmlOptions = {
        preserveViewport: true,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
      }

      var kmlLayer_1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://private.aatravel.co.nz/accommodation/1038668/proof14/final.kml", myKmlOptions);
      var kmlLayer_2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://private.aatravel.co.nz/accommodation/1038668/proof14/sep.kml", myKmlOptions);
      kmlLayer_1.setMap(map);
      kmlLayer_2.setMap(map);







      <!-- Asynchronous Loading -->
      function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
          '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }

      window.onload = loadScript;











      <!-- Let's create the legend -->


      var iconBase = 'https://i.imgur.com/';
      var icons = {
        travel: {
          name: 'AA Traveller office',
          icon: iconBase + '2BNbLmG.png'
        },
        isite: {
          name: 'I-Site',
          icon: iconBase + 'kx9a1sc.png'
        },

        accommodation: {
          name: 'Accommodation',
          icon: iconBase + 'BJ4o7ad.png'
        },

        camping: {
          name: 'Camping',
          icon: iconBase + 'EIcei8n.png'
        },


        food: {
          name: 'Food and Beverage',
          icon: iconBase + 'c5aaWcb.png'
        },


        toilets: {
          name: 'Toilets',
          icon: iconBase + 'ID2zzXg.png'
        },


        waters: {
          name: 'Drinking Water',
          icon: iconBase + '5u3yvH1.png'
        },


        todo: {
          name: 'Things to do',
          icon: iconBase + 'L3Z9xWv.png'
        },

        viewing: {
          name: 'Viewing points',
          icon: iconBase + 'DTf6oIp.png'
        }
      };
      // make one infoWindow
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      <!-- Adding the markers now -->
      function addMarker(feature) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: feature.position,
          icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
          map: map
        });
        // bind a to the marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
           infoWindow.setContent('Hi');
           infoWindow.open(map,this);
        });
        markers.push({
          marker: marker,
          type: feature.type
        });
      }

      // generic callback whenever an info window is clicked
      function openInfoWindow(marker, feature) {
         // i'm unsure of where you're data will come to populate the infoWindow
         infoWindow.setContent('ADD CONTENT HERE');
         infoWindow.open(map, marker); // open the infoWindow above the marker. the maps API will bind the close button click for you. 
      
      }

      <!-- Add the legend locations -->


      var features = [
        <!-- AA Travel -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.750002, 174.729471),
          type: 'travel'
        },




        <!-- I Site -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.226583, 175.335536),
          type: 'isite'
        },





        <!-- Accommodation -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.807404, 175.144404),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.808155, 175.474612),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.776782, 171.504106),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-43.820004, 172.965288),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-44.626974, 169.317827),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },


        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-46.522343, 168.455400),
          type: 'accommodation'
        },





        <!-- Camping -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.556301, 174.693964),
          type: 'camping'
        },






        <!-- Food and Beverage -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.368372, 176.847826),
          type: 'food'
        },





        <!-- Water -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.241622, 174.782397),
          type: 'waters'
        },







        <!-- Things to do -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.339016, 176.298510),
          type: 'todo'
        },






        <!-- Toilets -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-42.788153, 172.497240),
          type: 'toilets'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.878568, 173.837572),
          type: 'toilets'
        },





        <!-- Viewing spots -->
        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-43.890775, 171.838061),
          type: 'viewing'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.676004, 178.429858),
          type: 'viewing'
        },

        {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.278658, 173.763491),
          type: 'viewing'
        }

      ];

      for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
        addMarker(feature);
      }

      var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
      var i = 0;
      for (var key in icons) {
        var type = icons[key];
        var name = type.name;
        var icon = type.icon;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleType(this, event, \'' + key + '\')"><img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
        legend.appendChild(div);
        i++;
      }
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
    }

    function toggleType(elm, event, type) {
      var on = elm.checked;
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].type == type) {
          markers[i].marker.setMap(on ? map : null);
        }
      }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 html,
    body,
    #map_canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1000px;
      background-color: #2D333C;
    }
    #legend {
      font-family: Helvetica;
      color: #FFD900;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      padding: 25px;
      margin: 25px;
      border: 1px solid #FFD900;
    }
    #legend h3 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    #legend img {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div id="legend">
    <h3>Points of Interest</h3>
  </div>
```